# Sidebar not highlighting the current file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have two windows containing a corresponding set of files.  I have written some code in a WindowsCommand class which finds the file/view in window B which corresponds to the active file in window A.
I have been able to make Window B active and visible, find the relevant file/view, set focus to it, and select some text from it.
However the sidebar does not highlight the file/view which I have made active.  I have tried putting an insertion point in the view; makes no difference.
How can I make to sidebar highlight the active view?

Sorry that I am interchanging file & view terms

Comment: Some additional information - although I have set focus to the required view in window B, it is not made visible - which is probably why the file is not highlighted in the sidebar.  So the real question is how can I make the view visible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] so we can replicate your situation.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I worked on the code yesterday; making changes unrelated to the visibility issue, and the active view is now visible.  I have worked in the IT industry since the early 70s, and will quote an oft-used phrase - but I didn't touch that section of code!'